# I am not able to parse xml data using GDataXML

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-parsing, nsurlconnection, gdataxml

At first i have imported `#import "GDataXMLNode.h"` in .h file. Now this is my `XML` which i have to parse using `GDataXML` parser.

```
<SiteStats>
   <visitor>1</visitor>
   <uniqueVisitor>1</uniqueVisitor>
   <orderCount>0</orderCount>
   <revenue>null</revenue>
   <conversionRate>0</conversionRate>
   <newProduct>3</newProduct>
   <outOfStockProduct>0</outOfStockProduct>
</SiteStats>
```

Now, one thing to notice is that my this xml is coming from web. So I have used `NSUrlConnection` delegate to retrieve xml data.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseString);
    // other stuff here...
}
```

Here I get the `responseString` and then I parse it using the following code. But I'm not able to parse it.

```
 xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:responseString options:0 error:&errorOnStore];
if (nil == xmlDocument)    {
    NSLog(@"could not load xml file");
}
else    {
    NSLog(@"Loading desire xml");
    NSLog(@"%@", xmlDocument.rootElement);
    NSArray *getData = [[xmlDocument rootElement] elementsForName:@"SiteStats"];
    NSLog(@"%@",getData);
    records = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //[records retain];
    if(getData.count !=0 ){
        NSLog(@"data has");
    }
    //storing the car model in the mutable array
    for(GDataXMLElement *e in getData){
        NSLog(@"Enering in the xml file");
        [records addObject:e];

        NSString *Visitor = [[[e elementsForName:@"visitor"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"Visitor : %@",Visitor);

        NSString *UVisitor = [[[e elementsForName:@"uniqueVisitor"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"Unique Visitor : %@",UVisitor);
    }
}
```

I can get this value when i `NSLog(@"%@", xmlDocument.rootElement);`

```
 GDataXMLElement 0x1a4290: {type:1 name:SiteStats xml:"<SiteStats><visitor>4</visitor><uniqueVisitor>3</uniqueVisitor><orderCount>0</orderCount><revenue>0</revenue><conversionRate>0</conversionRate><newProduct>3</newProduct><outOfStockProduct>0</outOfStockProduct></SiteStats>"}
```

But i use `NSLog(@"%@",getData);` I do not get any data in `getData` array.

Can anybody tell me where is the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: where is the error? maybe post the output of your NSLog as well

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",getData);` print `(null)`.Please some how anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:responseString options:0 error:&errorOnStore];
if (nil == xmlDocument)    
{
    NSLog(@"could not load xml file");
}
else    
{
    NSLog(@"Loading desire xml");
    NSLog(@"%@", xmlDocument.rootElement);

    // skip this bits, you're trying to retrieve wrong element
    //NSArray *getData = [[xmlDocument rootElement] elementsForName:@"SiteStats"];
    //NSLog(@"%@",getData);
    records = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //[records retain];
    //if(getData.count !=0 )
    //{
        //NSLog(@"data has");
    //}
    //storing the car model in the mutable array
    //for(GDataXMLElement *e in getData)
    //{
        //NSLog(@"Enering in the xml file");
        //[records addObject:e];

        NSString *Visitor = [[[xmlDocument.rootElement elementsForName:@"visitor"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"Visitor : %@",Visitor);

        NSString *UVisitor = [[[xmlDocument.rootElement elementsForName:@"uniqueVisitor"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"Unique Visitor : %@",UVisitor);
    //}
}
```

EDIT:
`NSArray *getData = [[xmlDocument rootElement] elementsForName:@"SiteStats"];` in this line, you're trying to retrieve wrong element, element "SiteStats" is already the root element, so when you do that bit of code, what you're trying to do is looking for "SiteStats" inside of "SideStats"

```
<SiteStats>
   <SiteStats>
       <visitor>1</visitor>
       <uniqueVisitor>1</uniqueVisitor>
       <orderCount>0</orderCount>
       <revenue>null</revenue>
       <conversionRate>0</conversionRate>
       <newProduct>3</newProduct>
       <outOfStockProduct>0</outOfStockProduct>
   </SiteStats>
</SiteStats>
```

Your orignal code is likely to work if your XML looks something like above

Comment: This should get you running enough

Comment: Can you tell me why i am not getting data in the array???Though your answer is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the parsing you may also need to change the attribute "**xmlns**" in the tag

**< html >** by **noNSxml**. If this is not done then it will parse incorrectly.